# philosophical reason behind the number of equations to determine a plane or a line

Tags: geometry

It takes only one equation to write down the equation of a plane, but two equations for a straight line in three dimensions.  I know you can say that a straight line is an intersection of two planes, which then explains why it takes two equations to determine a line.  However, it only takes one equation to write down a line in two dimensions. So is there any philosophical reason to understand the number of equations needed for  different dimensions?

Comment: It is not philosophy but intuitive handwaving that can be formalised.  You start in a certain number of dimensions, and each linear equation constrains this by reducing the effective number of dimensions of the remaining solution space by one.  So starting with 3 dimensions, the first equation reduces the possibilities to a 2D space of solutions, the second equation (if not parallel) reduces that to a 1D space of solutions, and the third (if not parallel to that) reduces the possible solutions to a single point ($0$D).

Comment: Two dimensional space is just the part of 3D space satisfying the equation $z=0$, So for describing a line in 2D you have two equations to describe it in 3D. It becomes harder to visualise, but it goes the same way in four dimensions, 1 equation describes a 3D space, 2 equations describe a plane, 3 a line and 4 a point. And you can continue the pattern to even more dimensions.